# Android: What should I use for running a background long-term activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, timer

I am developing an android application using API 10 and I'm facing some issues. My application should send every 30 minutes a UDP packet to my desktop listen server. What I want to do:

- The background service should remain even if the application was closed (using back button from the device)
- To automatically start service if the device was restarted.

**My problems:**

I can't use startForeground(), because I am using API lvl 10. It was implemented in API 11.
The application wont stay in the background.

What have I done:

```
public class HeartbeatService extends Service{

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Log.e("er", "Started !");

      TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
      Log.e("err", "NBOW !");
         }
      };

      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(task, 1000); // every 1 sec for testing

      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
   }   

}
```

Using logcat I see only 2 lines generated "NBOW !" with the application open.

What should I do?

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      startService(new Intent(this, HeartbeatService.class));
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I can't use startForeground(), because I am using API lvl 10. It was implemented in API 11.

[`startForeground()` was added in API Level 5](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

> My application should send every 30 minutes a UDP packet to my desktop listen server.

Use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`, possibly [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Not only do you *not* need to keep a service running all the time just to get control every 30 minutes, but doing so is wasteful and increases the likelihood that the user will take steps to prevent your app from running.

> To automatically start service if the device was restarted

Use a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` to reschedule your `AlarmManager` events.

> What have I done

That not only requires you to waste the user's RAM watching the clock tick, but it will not work if the device is in sleep mode (which may or may not be an issue, depending upon your requirements).